Get server boost level for Discord bot
I'm writing a Discord bot in NodeJS. I'm wanting to make a check to see if the Discord server the bot is used on is boosted or not before the command fully executes. I have not been able to find out how to exactly get the server's boost level. Every attempt ends up in giving me the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'premiumSubscriptionCount')
0|jerma slots  |     at Client.<anonymous> (/root/JermaSlots/index.js:177:49)
0|jerma slots  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Snippet of the relevant code:
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
  await interaction.deferReply(); // Defer reply for processing

  const { commandName, options, guildId } = interaction;
  const userID = interaction.user.id;
  console.log(`Boost count: ${interaction.guild.premiumSubscriptionCount}`);

Before anyone asks, yes I've made sure Guilds is in my client intents. I don't know why this isn't working.
I've tried looking at Discord.js.org but I've had no luck with other things such as PremiumTier. They all have the exact same error message.

Please provide the full error - What exactly is null?

I have edited my post to include the full error. It's returning premiumSubscriptionCount as null.

Well seems, interaction.guild is undefined - What have you tried to resolve the issue?

I did not find any typo and the way you are trying to get the boost count seems correct.
But as the error says, it looks like your guild is null. Are you using this command in the guild or DM? Let's do basic and simple debugging. Check what you get from console.log(interaction.guild) or even console.log(interaction).
If you get normal data, the problem could be in approaching to the Discord API and getting data from Guild.

Try fetching the guild (e.g. AWAIT bot.guilds.fetch(interaction.guild) await is important!)
Check if the guild is available (if (interaction.guild.available))

By the way, premiumSubscriptionCount could be null (check docs here)
PS Are you using the latest discord.js version?
